# How to verify a Matrix js client writen by node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, matrix-synapse

I'm developing a matrix client with node & express.js. I need to do the following:

1. Connect to Matrix.
2. Enable e2e encryption.
3. Verify the logged in device (Current session).
4. Read messages of a specific room.

I did the following:

1. Connect to the home server and create client.
2. Login to the home server by username and password.
3. Re-create the client with new access token and device id.
4. Get a decoded code from the security phrase(Recovery key).
5. Now I need to verify the client with the recovery code instead of confirming emojis or scan a QR code (because I can't in my node client).

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  createClient,
  MatrixEvent,
  MatrixEventEvent,
} = require("matrix-js-sdk");
const { logger } = require("matrix-js-sdk/lib/logger");
require("isomorphic-fetch");
const Olm = require("@matrix-org/olm");
const { levels } = require("loglevel");
const { log } = require("console");
const { SyncState } = require("matrix-js-sdk/lib/sync");
global.Olm = Olm;

//define
const homeserverUrl = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
let accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
const username = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
const password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
const recoveryKey =
  "xxxxxxxxxxx";

//init the node express server
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

//create the client
let client = createClient({
  baseUrl: homeserverUrl,
});

//start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`backend client is running on port ${port}`);
});

client
  .login("m.login.password", {
    user: username,
    password: password,
  })
  .then(async (response) => {
    accessToken = response.access_token;
    deviceId = response.device_id;
    await client.setDeviceDetails(deviceId, {
      display_name: `Test Device ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)}`,
    });
    client = createClient({
      baseUrl: homeserverUrl,
      userId: username,
      deviceId: deviceId,
      accessToken: accessToken,
    });

    await client.initCrypto();

    fetchDecodedKey().then(async (keyInfo) => {
      const decodedKey = client.keyBackupKeyFromRecoveryKey(recoveryKey);
      const correct = await client.checkSecretStorageKey(
        decodedKey,
        keyInfo[1]
      );

      if (correct) {
        client.startClient();
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to log in:", err);
  });

client.once("sync", (state, prevState, data) => {
  const rooms = client.getRooms();
  log(rooms, "!frFFTrSpBpfnvFBsgP:homeserver.com");
  const _room = client.getRoom("!frFFTrSpBpfnvFBsgP:homeserver.com");
  log(_room);

  client
    .setRoomEncryption(_room.roomId, {
      decryption_key: decodedKey,
    })
    .then(async () => {
      log("done");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Failed to enable encryption:", error);
    });
});

client.on("Room.timeline", (event, room, toStartOfTimeline) => {
  console.log("Received event:", event);
});

//exit server
process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  console.log("Server is shutting down...");
  client
    .logout()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Client logged out successfully.");
      process.exit();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Failed to log out client:", error);
      process.exit();
    });
});

//secret fetcher.
const fetchDecodedKey = async () => {
  const key = await client.getDefaultSecretStorageKeyId();
  const secret = await client.crypto?.getSecretStorageKey(key);
  return secret;
};
```

Help me to verify the newly created device, please.